# how to design a custom loss function to add two loss

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, loss-function

I am using CNN to solve a regression problem in a supervised manner. i have input data(X_train) and the target data(y_train).

Comment: could you provide some example on how your code (model, objective function, data) looks like?

Comment: I think you first need to show a minimal working example of what you did. With the current information given it is not even possible to reengineer your problem.

Comment: can we get a minimal a.npy and b.npy (also the naming is not optimal)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251103/discussion-between-mrk-and-manas).

Comment: Customize the `train_step` of the model instead of using callbacks (see [here](https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/)). This is not a MWE and from the question it is still unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

from keras import backend as K
def custom_loss(loss1, loss2):
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
return loss1(y_true, y_pred) + loss2(y_true, y_pred)
return loss

## Example usage

from keras.losses import mean_squared_error
model.compile(loss=custom_loss(mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error), optimizer='adam')

Comment: plz provide interms of the code it is in single line. I get confused.

Answer (score -1):

After you declare your model, you can define a custom loss function in the `model.compile` step. Here's a snippet in the case you need to sum MSE and MAE:

```py
model = keras.Sequential([
    Dense(32, input_shape=(10,), activation='softmax')
])

def custom_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
    mse = MeanSquaredError()
    mae = MeanAbsoluteError()
    return mse(y_true, y_pred) + mae(y_true, y_pred)

model.compile(loss=custom_loss_function, optimizer='adam')
```